# Trying to use a jflap regex in scala

Tags: regex, scala, jflap

Pls see the following DFA   https://i.stack.imgur.com/iH3RM.png

created via JFLAP. When I convert to regex, JFLAP gives:

```
  p+(q+pq)(pq)*(λ+p)
```

When I  paste it in the Scala REPL :

```
  scala> val regex = "p+(q+pq)(pq)*(+p)".r
  java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '+' near index 14
  p+(q+pq)(pq)*(+p)
                ^
      at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
```

I have two simple questions.

1. Is that the right regex ? Why does it include a λ ?
2. How do I use it in Scala since the λ doesn't show up correctly when I paste in repl ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In formal regular expression notation `+` means "or". The regex you want to use is something like:

```
p|(q|pq)(pq)*p?
```

Comment: Wow thank you. I tried replacing + with |, and below works perfect.      
scala> val regex = "p|(q|pq)(pq)*(|p)".r regex:     scala.util.matching.Regex = p|(q|pq)(pq)*(|p)